# How to get the URL-safe key for Entities from GAE Datastore using Admin Console in the result list?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I'm trying to find an easy way to get data from GAE datastore using the cloud console. I can use GQL Query from https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query . The result list contains keys but not URL-safe keys. I wasn't able to find any function to transform keys to URL-safe keys to get them in the result list. Maybe I should use Google Cloud Shell?
Can someone help?

PS My Application is a java backend and I have no idea how to create and execute python's scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on an entity in the results list, you will see the url-safe key above the editable properties:

[image]

Comment: Yes. But I want to copy all result rows to Excel. So I need to get the url-safe key in the results list.

Comment: Maybe add that to the question ;)  Otherwise you can write a quick script to iterate all the entities you want to work with and get get the url-safe keys that way (e.g. `ndb.Key.urlsafe()` in Python).